# How to sort in a related table in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

This is my (simplified) code:

**Controller**

```
var userQuery = from u in _db.Users
                where u.Username.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                    || u.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                    || u.LastName.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                select u.FirmID;

var query = from f in _db.Firms
            where f.Name.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) 
                || f.Keyword.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) 
                    || f.KeywordList.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                    || userQuery.Contains(f.ID)
            select f;

// order by firm name
query = query.OrderBy(f => f.Name);
```

**User Model**

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int FirmID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FirmID")] 
    public virtual Firm Firm { get; set; }
}
```

**Firm Model**

```
public class Firm
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Keyword { get; set; }
    public string KeywordList { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

With this code, I get a list of Firms with Users which matches a certain search string. The list is ordered by Firms name. What I wanna do now, is to sort also by Users last name. How can I do that?

Now:

- Firm a

  - User b
  - User a
  - User c
- Firm b

  - User z
  - User d

Desired:

- Firm a

  - User a
  - User b
  - User c
- Firm b

  - User d
  - User z

Comment: `OrderBy` + `GroupBy` or `OrderBy(Firm)` + `ThenBy(user)`

Comment: Hmm shouldn't that be 
    `query = query.OrderBy(f => f.Name).ThenBy(f => f.Users.LastName);`
?

Comment: It was pseudo code... yes, you need to pass a delegate.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `query = query.OrderBy(f => f.Name).ThenBy(f => f.Users.LastName);` does not work. `LastName` isn't available for some reason...

Comment: That's because `Users` is a collection...

Comment: What else should it be? Sorry, I'm totally new to C# and ASP.NET...

Comment: Ah, I see! It should be a collection but the propertie isn't available because of that. But now, I'm still wondering how I could use `User` in `ThenBy()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tried like this

```
query.OrderBy(f => f.Name).Select(aux => new 
{
   Firm = aux.Firm,
   Users = aux.Users.OrderBy( x => x.Username )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally found the best solution for me:

```
query.OrderBy(f => f.Name)
     .ToList()
     .ForEach(f => f.Users = f.Users.OrderBy(u => u.LastName).ToList() );
```

This means, I don't have to create an anonymous select object (like Jorge's answer), which makes the model a lot easier to handle in a view.

Another solution could be to sort the users not in the controller but in the view. 
For example:

```
@foreach (var user in Model.Users.OrderBy(u => u.LastName)) {  }
```